# Simple Javascript that displays cells in Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know Javascript well. I also use Google Drive. I have a spreadsheet where:

1) On the left, I have questions (about International business, but it could be about anything)
2) On the right, I have the answers

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17zMVbzevOV7HNpGIjkFKi_l_kUeuX7NX2jG5GIL8Jow/edit#gid=0

I want to write a simple script that will:

1) Pick a random cell from the sheet (column A), and display it (the question)
2) When I press space (or whatever), it shows the column B of the same raw (the answer)

I started the "script editor" on the spreadsheet, but I am stuck: I have no idea how to use it, where to get documentation, or even how to approach the problem. Specifically:

1) How do I interact with the sheet? (that is, get its data)
2) How do I "display" anything?
3) What's the "Publish as Webapp" for?

Any directions, hints, docs, ideas, techniques, rough code, will be most helpful!

**UPDATE**

Actually, I managed to write this simple script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    Logger.log(row);
  }
}
```

So, the remaining questions now are:

1) How do I get this data displayed "somewhere", and get the user's input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Web App using [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/#create_html_files) in script editor, or use [ContentSrvice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service#properties) and make an API with Google SpreadSheet as DB

I think [this tutorial](https://www.topcoder.com/blog/a-simple-webapp-using-google-apps-scripts/) can help you for start.

Also there are [useful samples](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles#integration) of google apps scripts.